# Openlayers and catching drag event

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Im using OpenLayers and i need to be able to tell difference between when map has been moved by my own scrip or by user. Yeah im aware that i can use moveend. But it also triggers when the same script is moving or repositioning map based on incoming data from ajax calls. So moveend or other map events wont work.

I did some googling and found OpenLayers.Hander.Drag. But all that i managed with it was to stop users from dragging map.

My script:

```
this.dragger = new OpenLayers.Handler.Drag('',{
        'dragStart': function(evt){
            this.userdragged = true;
            console.log('drag');
        }},{
        'map':this.mymap
        });
this.dragger.activate();
```

As you can see, i tried to set userdragged variable to true to use this same variable in moveend event later. Unfortunately all this did was to stop my map from beeing draggable.

Can someone assist me please?

Alan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

What got it working was :

```
dragcontrol = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({'map':this.mymap, 'panMapDone':function(evt){
    this.userdragged  = true;
    console.log('drag');
}});
dragcontrol.draw();
this.mymap.addControl(dragcontrol);
dragcontrol.activate();
```

Booyaka!

Edit:
Actually this.userdragged wont work in there... the scope of this is different there. you would need to do something like var that = this; before that object initialization and use that.userdragged = true....

Edit2:
I later found, that this panMapDone function overwrites DragPans own method which has same name. With just my previous example, you can end up with map that results in vector features going out of sync with map, when user drags map. To stop that from happening, you should copy the original functionality into that function too... to make it look something like that:

```
dragcontrol = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({'map':this.mymap, 'panMapDone':function(xy){
        if(this.panned) {
            var res = null;
            if (this.kinetic) {
                res = this.kinetic.end(xy);
            }
            this.map.pan(
                this.handler.last.x - xy.x,
                this.handler.last.y - xy.y,
                {dragging: !!res, animate: false}
            );
            if (res) {
                var self = this;
                this.kinetic.move(res, function(x, y, end) {
                    self.map.pan(x, y, {dragging: !end, animate: false});
                });
            }
            this.panned = false;
        }
        that.userdragged  = true;
            // do whatever you want here
    }});
    dragcontrol.draw();
    this.mymap.addControl(dragcontrol);
    dragcontrol.activate();
```

Alan

Comment: Great that you got it to work! What does the draw() function do to the solution?

Comment: draw creates and activates the actual handler. http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragPan-js.html [quote]draw - Creates a Drag handler, using panMap and panMapDone as callbacks.[/quote]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Drag-js.html) on Drag handlers, it states that it's supposed to be used with a Control object. Are you using it that way? Maybe the code snippet doesn't show it?

"If a handler is being used without a control, the handlers setMap method must be overridden to deal properly with the map."

I haven't tried it, but it seems as you should go for something like this:

```
var myControl = new OpenLayers.Control();

var dragger = new OpenLayers.Handler.Drag{
    control: myControl,
    callbacks: { 'done': function() { // do something }},
    options: {}
}

myMap.addControl(myControl);
myControl.activate();
```

Comment: Tried this, but it wont work at all. At least i can not determine in any way, that its working. With my own script i could at least tell, that its working because it gave me some result - stopped map from moving. The line you quoted ("If handler is beeing used without a control...") - i specified map in options and thats what stopped my map working. Without that map declaration in options, it did not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting an example here of executing an arbitrary function when the user drag the map, without interfering with the normal click-drag used to pan the map, because this page was the most frequent result during my search to find how to do that.

```
var CustomDragControl = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {

    defaultHandlerOptions: {
        'stopDown': false
        /* important, otherwise it prevent the click-drag event from 
           triggering the normal click-drag behavior on the map to pan it */
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
        );
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
            this, arguments
        ); 
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Drag(
            this, {
                'down': this.onDown //could be also 'move', 'up' or 'out'
            }, this.handlerOptions
        );
    }, 

    onDown: function(evt) {
        // do something when the user clic on the map (so on drag start)
        console.log('user clicked down on the map');
    }
});
```

then add the control to you map's controls list when creating the map instance, or with a map.addControl(), with

```
new CustomDragControl ({'autoActivate': true})
```

Comment: Does this solve the OP's problem - triggering functions on user drag but not on ajax-driven movement?

Comment: as far as I can see, yes, only the user actions are caught.

Answer (score 1):

i have use that in OpenLayers 6:

```
map.on('pointerdrag', function (event) {
    is_map_center = false;
})
```

hf gl!